# Accessing MySQL database in Netbeans Java (no suitable driver)

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

In Netbeans (8.0.2), under services, I've connected to my local MySQL and I am able to view tables and execute MySQL queries. I've tried the following code

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clresdb";
String uname = "root";
String pword = "password";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, pword);
```

I've commented out the driver and gotten "driver not found". But, when I include the new instance for the driver, I get class not found. Am I using the wrong class name? How do I find out the correct name? How am I able to view the data if I have something wrong?

Comment: did you add mysql driver to libraries ?

Comment: Also, `Class.forName()` would suffice. No need to call `newInstance()`

Comment: No, I didn't have the driver in my libraries. I right-clicked on libraries, selected Add Library, scrolled down to MySQL JDBC Driver, added it, and was successful. (I also took out newInstance()). Thanks, this worked